# @ngx-translate ''setTranslation" and "set" not working

Tags: angular, translate, ngx-translate

I am using @ngx-translate setTranslation method to update several values in runtime depending on some condition in the code.

JSON file with translations look like this:

```
"example":{
    "tab":{
        "firstValue": "someValue"
    }
}
```

setTranslation function is called like this:

```
this.translateService.setTranslation('es', {
            "example": {
                "tab": {
                    "firstValue": "otherValue",
                }
            },
        });
```

This:

```
this.translateService.get("example.tab.firstValue").subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

always returns *"someValue"*, but it should return updated value - *"otherValue"*

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

My first response to this was probably not fully solving the problem. When I add objects with the same keys as already existing objects, the 'shouldMerge' flag didn't make a difference. So I took another approach:
I first get translations for a given language, this returns an object and then manipulate this object and after that I set translation with this manipulated object. 
In my case I now have a method which looks like this:

```
private addDynamicTranslation(section:string,culture:string,k:string,v:string){
    //if key already exists: overwrite it, if not create it
    if(this.valueMapper.translateService.getLangs().includes(culture)){
       this.valueMapper.translateService.getTranslation(culture).subscribe((t:Object)=>{
            if(t.hasOwnProperty(section)){
               if(t[section].hasOwnProperty(k)) t[section][k]=v;
               else Object.defineProperty(t[section], k, {value:v, writable:true, configurable:true, enumerable:true});
            }
            else{
                var obj={};
                Object.defineProperty(obj, k, {value:v, writable:true, configurable:true, enumerable:true});
                Object.defineProperty(t, section, obj);
            };
            this.valueMapper.translateService.setTranslation(culture,t);
        })
    }
}
```